# Going through list a couple of times

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
def summify(array, number):
    returnList = []
    if type(array).__name__ == 'list':
        for k in range(0, len(array)):
            for kk in range(k, len(array)):
                if array[k] + array[kk] == number:
                    returnList.append([array[k],array[kk]])
    else:
        return []
```

I don't really know what is the best title for this problem. What I am trying to do is given an array(python list), and then given a specific number in a parameter, I want the function to return a group of items from the list which will add up to that number.

For example,

```
>>> summify([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 10)
[[1,2,3,4]
 [1,5,4]
 [2,3,5]]
 ...
```

and every other group that will add up to 10.

Comment: Check out the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a desired length of array but here is one way to do it:

```
import itertools

def summify(num_list, target):
    for v in range(len(num_list)):
        for combo in itertools.combinations(num_list, v):
            if sum(combo) == target:
                print combo


t = range(1,11)

summify(t, 10)

(10,)
(1, 9)
(2, 8)
(3, 7)
(4, 6)
(1, 2, 7)
(1, 3, 6)
(1, 4, 5)
(2, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Here is another way:

```
def summify(num_list, num):
    for v in range(len(num_list)):
        combos = filter(lambda x: sum(x) == num, itertools.combinations(num_list, v))
        if combos:
            print combos

summify(t, 10)

[(10,)]
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6)]
[(1, 2, 7), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```